# Find regular expression in one column and add to a new column in same dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (TBB) as follows

```
X.CHROM    POS        INFO

 chr1     134324   SAMPLE=LNGHJ;
 chr2     2333     SAMPLE=dd;GERP;.;
 chr2      3334     SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;CDC=dd;
```

I would like to extract everything between each semicolon and put it in its own column so that the result would look like

```
X.CHROM    POS        INFO                       
chr1     134324       SAMPLE=LNGHJ;            SAMPLE=LNGHJ    
chr2     2333         SAMPLE=dd;GERP;DDS=3;    SAMPLE=dd       GERP   DDS=3   
chr2      3334        SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;        SAMPLE=         GERP   DDS
```

I tried this

```
TBB3 <- TBB[grep("SAMPLE.*?;", TBB$INFO), ]
TBB4<-cbind(TBB3,TBB)
```

but the columns are the wrong sizes relative to each other and obviously I would have to repeat this for each word after a semicolon so not very efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `stringi::stri_split_fixed`

```
library(stringi)
cbind(TBB, stri_split_fixed(TBB$INFO, ";", simplify = TRUE, omit_empty = TRUE))
#   X.CHROM    POS                  INFO            1    2     3
# 1    chr1 134324         SAMPLE=LNGHJ; SAMPLE=LNGHJ           
# 2    chr2   2333 SAMPLE=dd;GERP;DDS=3;    SAMPLE=dd GERP DDS=3
# 3    chr2   3334     SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;      SAMPLE= GERP   DDS
```

Comment: and Topic Starter - I needed similar solution over the weekend (but put it on hold due to holiday), so thank you! However, in the original post there are 4 "items" in between semicolons in row with `3334`, while other rows have 3. Will that break generality?

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov it won't brake, but it will create a separate entry for `.` if that what you mean. Though that could be also dealt with a proper regex I guess.

Comment: Hm `stringi` seems damn sexy, have to look more closely at it. :-)

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov, for example `gsub(";([[:punct:]]+);", ";", "SAMPLE=dd;GERP;.;")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I meant `CDC=dd`, but I guess it will simply create column `4` for this one and add `NA` for the rest of rows

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov, Yes, exactly like in LukeAs answer. But you can also remove all the entries that have *only* punctuations (no meaningful text) using the regex above

Comment: Perfect. Worked exactly as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could also try good old `plyr::rbind.fill` or `dplyr::rbind_list` in combination with `strsplit`:

```
cbind(TBB, 
      do.call(dplyr::rbind_list, 
              lapply(strsplit(as.character(TBB$INFO), split = ";", fixed = TRUE), 
                     function(x) 
                       as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = F))
              )
)
#   X.CHROM    POS                     INFO           V1   V2   V3     V4
# 1    chr1 134324            SAMPLE=LNGHJ; SAMPLE=LNGHJ <NA> <NA>   <NA>
# 2    chr2   2333        SAMPLE=dd;GERP;.;    SAMPLE=dd GERP    .   <NA>
# 3    chr2   3334 SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;CDC=dd;      SAMPLE= GERP  DDS CDC=dd
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(TBB, 'INFO', ';', drop=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the package `base` from the `R` library:

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "X.CHROM    POS        INFO
chr1     134324   SAMPLE=LNGHJ;
chr2     2333     SAMPLE=dd;GERP;.;
chr2      3334     SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;CDC=dd;")


(dd1 <- read.table(text = as.character(dd$INFO), sep = ';', fill = NA,
                   na.strings = c('', '.','NA')))

#             V1   V2   V3     V4 V5
# 1 SAMPLE=LNGHJ <NA> <NA>   <NA> NA
# 2    SAMPLE=dd GERP <NA>   <NA> NA
# 3      SAMPLE= GERP  DDS CDC=dd NA

cbind(dd, dd1[, -ncol(dd1)])

#     X.CHROM    POS                     INFO           V1   V2   V3     V4
#   1    chr1 134324            SAMPLE=LNGHJ; SAMPLE=LNGHJ <NA> <NA>   <NA>
#   2    chr2   2333        SAMPLE=dd;GERP;.;    SAMPLE=dd GERP <NA>   <NA>
#   3    chr2   3334 SAMPLE=;GERP;DDS;CDC=dd;      SAMPLE= GERP  DDS CDC=dd
```

Comment: I keep forgetting the simple base R option

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table v1.9.5+`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, paste0("INFO", 1:4) := tstrsplit(INFO, ";", fixed=TRUE)]
```